# Change the value of an object data member through a pointer to that object

Tags: c++, pointers

I can change the value `pTest` points to with `*pTest = 100;`:

```
int main() {
    int *pTest = new int;
    *pTest = 100;
    cout << " Value of pTest " << *pTest;
}
```

But I can't change this object's data member with `*pCurrPtr->m_Data = 1;`:

```
class CNode {
public:
    int m_Data;
    CNode *m_pLinkedList;
};

int main() {
    CNode *pHeadPtr, *pCurrPtr, *pTailPtr, *pDeleteThisNode;
    pCurrPtr = new CNode;
    pCurrPtr->m_Data = 1;//won't compile with *pCurrPtr->m_Data = 1;

    cout << "data is " << pCurrPtr->m_Data;
}
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 7):

When you use `*pCurrPtr->m_Data` it's equal to `*(pCurrPtr->m_Data)`, which means you're trying to dereference the `m_Data` member. And `m_Data` is not a pointer and as such can't be dereferenced.

If you want to dereference the (actual) pointer `pCurrPtr` that's already done with the "arrow" operator `->`: `pCurrPtr->m_Data` is equal to `(*pCurrPtr).m_Data`.

Answer (score 6):

This is the C++ syntax.

`pCurrPtr->m_Data` is equivalent to `(*pCurrPtr).m_Data`:

- dereference `pCurrPtr` (which is a pointer to a `CNode`),
- and access the `m_Data` member variable (which is of type `int`) of that object.

=> All good.

`*pCurrPtr->m_Data` is equivalent to `*(pCurrPtr->m_Data)` and `*((*pCurrPtr).m_Data)`:

- dereference `pCurrPtr` (which is a pointer to a `CNode`),
- access the `m_Data` member variable (which is of type `int`) of that object,
- ... to dereference it.

=> But `m_Data` is not a pointer to an `int`, it *is* an `int`. And this should be what your compiler complains about.